# Flutter : Voice command to give user weather and date time update

Tags: flutter

I want to create an application that work on voice command. In this application there is two options when user ask for weather or time update the application get the current weather and give update about weather in voice and the same functionality for time and date. Please help me how I can achieve this in flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use :

https://alan.app/docs/tutorials/flutter/integrating-flutter

or use:

https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text

```
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;

    stt.SpeechToText speech = stt.SpeechToText();
    bool available = await speech.initialize( onStatus: statusListener, onError: errorListener );
    if ( available ) {
        speech.listen( onResult: resultListener );
    }
    else {
        print("The user has denied the use of speech recognition.");
    }
    // some time later...
    speech.stop()
```

Then treat specific words as commands:

```
void resultListener(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    ++resultListened;
    print('Result listener $resultListened');
    setState(() {
      lastWords = '${result.recognizedWords} - ${result.finalResult}';
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help its help ma a lot and save a lot of my time. I am using Alan plugin for voice command. I am confuse how I handle Alan voice output with dynamically. for example user say weather update Using Alan command I hit the API but after getting data from API how Alan play that weather update?